# Efficient way to monitor or watch ps -ef for unknown process with known string

Tags: bash, security, monitoring, watch, ps

I am trying to determine which applications run containing a known string that could exist for an unknown process name as part of the arguments of the commands executed.

For example: weird-process.sh XXX YYY ZZZ

Where I know what ZZZ is, and nothing else. A simple if statement dumps the string to a txt file for inspection.

A script called process-check.sh works

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
CMD=$(ps -efwww | grep "$1" |grep -v "grep\|process-check.sh")
if [[ ! -z $CMD ]];
then
    echo $CMD >> process-check.txt
else
    continue
fi
done
```

Are there linux builtin or existing commands that could monitor, watch or perhaps record process execution better given the not knowing which process restriction?

Comment: No there is not.

Comment: Though this is on-topic here as well, I think you'd get better answers on [unix.se].

Answer (score 0):

There is no *built in* linux command to watch for a process with certain arguments, and your script is pretty good!

To more fully realize the goal of having a script that can "determine which applications run containing a known string that could exist for an unknown process name as part of the arguments of the commands executed", Here are a few scripts that you may find useful.

## Tricks used

- List all system processes `ps -efwww`
- Remove the first 8 *irrelevant fields*: `ps -efwww | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f8-`
- Only print lines that have at least 4 words (command + 3args) `awk 'NF>=1+3'`
- Only print lines that contain a specified keyword `grep "${1}"`

## Script variations

#### Either the program name or any argument must match query string

```sh
ps -efwww | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f8- | awk 'NF>=1+3' | grep "${1}"
```

#### Any argument must match query string

```sh
ps -efwww | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f9- | awk 'NF>=3' | grep "${1}"
```

#### The third argument must match query string

```sh
ps -efwww | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f11- | awk 'NF>=1' | cut -d' ' -f1 | grep "${1}"
```

Simply save one of these one-liners in your `process-check.sh` script and do a `watch process-check.sh` Toss in a `tee -a logfile.log` or a `>>` to create a record.